# Javascript - What is the best way to remove alternate repeating character in a given string with time complexity O(n) and Space Complexity was O(1)?

Tags: javascript, string

In Javascript, What is the best way to remove alternate repeating character in a given string with time complexity O(n) and Space Complexity was O(1)?

// Example: Input: “you have beautiful eyes”
// Output: ”you have btiful es”

Comment: That's not alternate *strings*, it's alternate *characters* within the same string.

Comment: please add the rule for getting `g` for example.

Comment: The output seems to be derived from "you **got** beautiful eyes" not the given input. And the output doesn't miss alternate letters, either - I'd expect "**y**o**u** **g**o**t** **b**e**a**u**t**i**f**u**l** **e**y**e**s"

Comment: This is pretty much removing all duplicates..
var t = Input.split('')
    .filter((a, index, self) => {
        return self.indexOf(a) == index
    }).join('')

console.log(t)

Comment: Is this *alternate* or *duplicate*? The first will give you (or remove) every second character "**y**o**u** **h**a**v**e**<space>**b**e**a**u**t**i**f**u**l**<space>**e**y**e**s**" -> "yuhv euiu ys". Duplicate will remove characters that already showed up -> "you havebtifls"

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and remove visited characters and use a `Set` for visited characters in a word, then take that character.

```
you have beautiful eyes    string
-----------------------    ------------------------------
   _    _         _        keep spaces
you have b   tif l    s    filtering with visited
                     e     additional filtering with word
you have b   tif l   es    result
```

```js
var string = 'you have beautiful eyes',
    visited = new Set,
    word = new Set,
    result = Array
        .from(string, c =>
            c === ' ' && (word = new Set) ||
            !visited.has(c) && visited.add(c) ||
            word.has(c) || !word.add(c)
                ? c
                : ''
        )
        .join('');
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Still output is not "you have btiful es"

Comment: right, but you missed to add the rule behind of selective removements.

Comment: @JankiDepala but *why* would you get that output? You never explained the rules here. You said "alternate" when you seem to mean "duplicate", which are two completely different things. Moreover, even under duplicate rules, why would you get "es" at the end, when "hav**e**" appears earlier, so you now have two "e" characters? Moreover, the spaces are preserved, so this isn't even truly "duplicates".

Comment: It should be alternate and duplicate both. It is simple otherwise I assume.. It should be alternate repeating character..

Comment: what is in sense of a string an *alternate* value?

Comment: I can only guess it's keeping "hav*e** ..ey**e**s" but...there is a lot of guessing happening in this question already. I am really not sure.

Comment: so *alternate* could mean to add a removed character, if it appears a second (or third) time in a word.